How to bind Svelte Store when the value inside object?
I have a custom component InputGroup. It can render checkbox or radio type of input. The selected value is always Svelte Store. But the first store is top of scope, the second inside object. I use $: bind:group={$selectedStore}. Because my version of Svelte does have not syntax $rootObject.svelteStore.value, only has $svelteStore.value.
Usecase
stores.playerTypes contains an array, stores.preview contains the object.
enum PlayerType {
    PREVIEW = "preview",
    STREAM = "stream"
}

type Preview = {
    showMode: string
}


// Root component
{#await getSvelteStoreArray(["playerTypes", "preview"]) then stores }
  <InputGroup type='checkbox' selectedStore={stores.playerTypes} />
  <Preview value={stores.preview} />
{/await}

// Preview component
<InputGroup type='radio' bind:selectedValue={$value.showMode} />

As I wrote above, we can't write the next line in the root component. So Preview component is the wrapper.
<InputGroup type='radio' bind:selectedValue={$stores.preview.showMode} />

Issue
The InputGroup works as expected, but in order for the component can get the store and pure value I create two variables selectedStore and selectedValue. Is there another way to do this more simple way?
I have tried to add expressions like bind:group={isStore(selected)? $selected : selected}. But occurs error: Can only bind to an identifier (e.g. 'foo') or a member expression (e.g. 'foo.bar' or 'foo[baz]').
<script type="ts">
  import { Checkbox, List, Li, Radio } from 'flowbite-svelte'
  import { SvelteStore } from '../../modules/storage'
  import TwoLineLabel from './TwoLineLabel.svelte'

  export let id = ''
  export let title = ''
  export let description = ''
  export let items = []
  export let selectedStore: SvelteStore<any>
  export let selectedValue: any
  export let type: 'checkbox' | 'radio'
</script>

<div class="flex flex-col justify-between items-start">
  <TwoLineLabel {title} {description} />
  <List tag="ul" list="none">
    {#each items as item}
      <Li class="rounded p-2 pl-0">
        {#if type == 'checkbox'}
          {#if selectedStore && selectedStore.subscribe}
            <Checkbox class="font-normal cursor-pointer" bind:group={$selectedStore} value={item.value}>{item.name}</Checkbox>
          {:else}
            <Checkbox class="font-normal cursor-pointer" bind:group={selectedValue} value={item.value}>{item.name}</Checkbox>
          {/if}
        {:else if type == 'radio'}
          {#if selectedStore && selectedStore.subscribe}
            <Radio class="font-normal cursor-pointer" bind:group={$selectedStore} value={item.value}>{item.name}</Radio>
          {:else}
            <Radio class="font-normal cursor-pointer" bind:group={selectedValue} value={item.value}>{item.name}</Radio>
          {/if}
        {/if}
      </Li>
    {/each}
  </List>
</div>

